# How to stop GNOME from adding bars, clocks, menu, etc. every time I restart X or log in?

Tags: gnome-panel, twinview, dconf

I have two monitors and want for each display its own Xscreen (i.e., Twinview feature must be off).

Turned out that Gnome has been duplicating clocks, bars, workspace, etc. every time I log in or restart X. I installed `dconf-editor` and found that under `org>gnome>gnome-panel>layout`, the fields `object-id-list` and `toplevel-id-list` had many entries instead of just one value for each attribute. Right now I am able to delete all of them and leave just one for each attribute and it looks fine.

The problem is that every time you log in or restart X, it does the same thing, and keep adding entries to those fields automatically. I couldn't find where the `dconf-editor` profile text files are saved.

How can I set this permanently?

Answer (score 0):

Which ubuntu version you are using?

If it is 12.04 amd64 you can go to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/1083811) launchpad bug and download last two attached .deb packages which includes fix.

In ubuntu 13.04 is included only half fix for this bug - panels will be created on correct screens, but you will have to manually add objects to other screen panels.